# How to declare a constant map in Golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to declare to constant in Go, but it is throwing an error.

This is my code:

```golang
const myMap = map[int]string{
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
}
```

This is the error

```
map[int]string{…} (value of type map[int]string) is not constant
```

Comment: golang doesn't allow const maps. here is a good explanation why https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/993ujz/why_is_not_possible_to_create_a_constant_map/

Answer (score 264, accepted):

In Go, a map unfortunately cannot be `const`. You can declare it as a regular variable like this with the `var` keyword:

```golang
var myMap = map[int]string{
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
}
```

Inside a function, you may declare it with the short assignment syntax:

```golang
func main() {
    myMap := map[int]string{
        1: "one",
        2: "two",
        3: "three",
    }
}
```

[Try it out on the Go playground.](https://go.dev/play/p/_k3TgBDbf28)

Comment: I think the author means how to protect the map from unwanted changes

Answer (score 37):

You can create constants in many different ways:

```
const myString = "hello"
const pi = 3.14 // untyped constant
const life int = 42 // typed constant (can use only with ints)
```

You can also create a enum constant:

```
const ( 
   First = 1
   Second = 2
   Third = 4
)
```

You can not create constants of maps, arrays and it is written in [effective go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#constants):

> Constants in Go are just that—constant. They are created at compile
>   time, even when defined as locals in functions, and can only be
>   numbers, characters (runes), strings or booleans. Because of the
>   compile-time restriction, the expressions that define them must be
>   constant expressions, evaluatable by the compiler. For instance, 1<<3
>   is a constant expression, while math.Sin(math.Pi/4) is not because the
>   function call to math.Sin needs to happen at run time.

Comment: so it's more like a C++11 constexpr... why math.Sin is not a constexpr function, then!

Comment: Your statements are correct, but the question was about creating a map that is constant.

Comment: @jzer7 can you explain me why my answer is irrelevant? He asked how to create something, I told him that this is not possible. Explained what is possible and gave a citation from the docs why exactly is it not possible to do what he wants.

Answer (score 18):

You may emulate a map with a closure:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/27457144/10278

func romanNumeralDict() func(int) string {
    // innerMap is captured in the closure returned below
    innerMap := map[int]string{
        1000: "M",
        900:  "CM",
        500:  "D",
        400:  "CD",
        100:  "C",
        90:   "XC",
        50:   "L",
        40:   "XL",
        10:   "X",
        9:    "IX",
        5:    "V",
        4:    "IV",
        1:    "I",
    }

    return func(key int) string {
        return innerMap[key]
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(romanNumeralDict()(10))
    fmt.Println(romanNumeralDict()(100))

    dict := romanNumeralDict()
    fmt.Println(dict(400))
}
```

[Try it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/B8I_mfPlue)

Comment: (TestMostSoldRecommender?)

Comment: It is in fact a possible solution. However, since the author did not explain anything (and put everything inside a weirdly-named test case), the answer looks incorrect. The logic is: (1) Create an anonymous function (2) The anonymous function encapsulates the `map` (3) The anonymous function returns "a function that accepts an int and returns a string" (4) The returned function does the int -> string mapping by using the `map` (5) Execute the anonymous function immediately and assign the returned function to a variable. This variable could be used like a function, and the effect is like a map.

Comment: this is not ideal, we still missing important  map capabilities, such as `len` , key list etc

Answer (score 5):

And as suggested above by [Siu Ching Pong -Asuka Kenji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142239/siu-ching-pong-asuka-kenji) with the function which in my opinion makes more sense and leaves you with the convenience of the map type without the function wrapper around:

```
   // romanNumeralDict returns map[int]string dictionary, since the return
       // value is always the same it gives the pseudo-constant output, which
       // can be referred to in the same map-alike fashion.
       var romanNumeralDict = func() map[int]string { return map[int]string {
            1000: "M",
            900:  "CM",
            500:  "D",
            400:  "CD",
            100:  "C",
            90:   "XC",
            50:   "L",
            40:   "XL",
            10:   "X",
            9:    "IX",
            5:    "V",
            4:    "IV",
            1:    "I",
          }
        }

        func printRoman(key int) {
          fmt.Println(romanNumeralDict()[key])
        }

        func printKeyN(key, n int) {
          fmt.Println(strings.Repeat(romanNumeralDict()[key], n))
        }

        func main() {
          printRoman(1000)
          printRoman(50)
          printKeyN(10, 3)
        }
```

[Try this at play.golang.org.](https://play.golang.org/p/lrvOTr1zKB4)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the nicest looking code, but you can achieve somewhat of a constant map-like thing using anonymous structs and closures:

Voila!

```golang
type MapGet[T any, V any] func(T) (V, bool)

var (
    myMap = struct {
        Get MapGet[int, string]
    }{
        Get: func(mp map[int]string) MapGet[int, string] {
            return func(key int) (string, bool) {
                v, found := mp[key]
                return v, found
            }
        }(map[int]string{
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three",
        }),
    }
)

func main() {
    v, _ := myMap.Get(1)
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

https://goplay.tools/snippet/SrAMRsBOPn9

Answer (score -5):

As stated above to define a map as constant is not possible.
But you can declare a global variable which is a struct that contains a map.

The Initialization would look like this:

```
var romanNumeralDict = struct {
    m map[int]string
}{m: map[int]string {
    1000: "M",
    900: "CM",
    //YOUR VALUES HERE
}}

func main() {
    d := 1000
    fmt.Printf("Value of Key (%d): %s", d, romanNumeralDict.m[1000])
}
```

Comment: Why not just the make the map the global variable? Why wrap it in the struct?

Comment: This doesn't make the map constant, you can still do `romanNumeralDict.m[1000] = "New value"`